# Oracle Query con valores duplicados

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-11g, toad

tengo una duda con esta query me empezó a fallar y me trae un registro 2 veces, que podrá ser? Esto es una BD Oracle.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Query:

```
select
gdm.id,
gdm.pesogramos,
gdm.nrogalpon galpon,
gdm.nrolote lote, 
gdm.id_lote,
gdm.edadsemana,
a.plu,
a.descripcion descart,
d.descripcion division  ,
gdm.id_galpondivision
from gpa_galponpesadarecria gdm
inner join gpa_galpondivisionstock      s on gdm.id_galpondivision=s.id_galpondivision           
INNER JOIN gpa_galpondivisionarticulo   da ON da.id = s.id_galpondivisionarticulo                
INNER JOIN gpa_articulo                 a ON da.id_articulo = a.id 
INNER JOIN gpa_galpondivision           d ON da.id_galpondivision = d.id  
where gdm.id_lote= 29 
order by gdm.edadsemana,gdm.id_galpondivision
```

Comment: Habría que ver el contenido de las tablas que usas

Comment: Usa `SELECT a.*, d.*, gdm.*` y encuentra el(los) valores que difieren en los registros repetidos.